# How to change Jackson's default concrete map type?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a very simple Jackson code to deserialize a nested JSON object:

```
public class MapTest
{
  public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception
  {
    final String ser = "{\"nested\":{\"k1\":\"v1\",\"k2\":\"v2\",\"k3\":\"v3\"}}";
    final Map<String, Object> deser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(ser, new TypeReference<TreeMap<String, Object>>(){});
    System.out.println("Class of deser's nested object is " + deser.get("nested").getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

When I run this I obtain the following output:

```
Class of deser's nested object is LinkedHashMap
```

However I want the nested map to be deserialized as a `TreeMap` rather than as a `LinkedHashMap` as per the output.  How can I tell Jackson to default to use a `TreeMap` when deserializing?

Reading through the documentation the closest thing I found was the ability to define concrete classes for abstract types through `addAbstractTypeMapping()` in a module but I've tried every superclass and instance of `LinkedHashMap` in an attempt to do this and nothing seems to work.

This is using Jackson 2.4.2, although if there is a way to do this that requires a higher version I would be able to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Module's `addAbstractTypeMapping()` is indeed the way to achive mapping in general. But the problem may be due to recursive nature of deserialization; because inner values are considered to be of type `java.lang.Object`.

However, I think there were indeed fixes to this part in 2.5, so I would specifically checking to see if 2.5.0 would work, once you add abstract mapping from `Map` to `TreeMap`.
If this does not work, please file a bug at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues since it should work.

Comment: Tried it with 2.5.0 and same result; bug posted as requested.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it turns out to be something easy to fix, as this is something that should work the way you used it.

Comment: FWIW, this -- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/700 -- is the issue, and it will be fixed in Jackson 2.6 (difficult to backport since issue goes quite deep for case of `java.lang.Object`, aka "untyped" mapping)