# Is it possible to de/serialize map itself polymorphic in jackson?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson, polymorphism

I've searched a lot and only find questions about polymorphic deserialization on the content inside a map. Is it possible to polymorphic deserializing the map itself?

For example, I have a Book class contains a Map as a member variable.

```
public class Book {
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Object> reviews;

    @JsonCreator
    public Book(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.reviews = map;
    }
}
```

Another class have a list of Book class.

```
public class Shelf {

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
       return this.books;
    }
}
```

And a test class. One book's review map is a Hashtable and another book's review map is a HashMap.

```
public class Test {

    private Shelf shelf;

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {
        Map<String, Object> review1 = new Hashtable<>(); // Hashtable here
        review1.put("test1", "review1");
        Map<String, Object> review2 = new HashMap<>(); // HashMap here
        review2.put("test2", "review2");

        List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();
        books.add(new Book(review1));
        books.add(new Book(review2));
        shelf = new Shelf();
        shelf.setBooks(books);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
//        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(shelf);
        System.out.println(json);

        Shelf sh = mapper.readValue(json, Shelf.class);
        for (Book b : sh.getBooks()) {
            System.out.println(b.getReviews().getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

The test output

```
{
  "name" : "TestShelf",
  "books" : [ {
    "reviews" : {
      "test1" : "review1"
    }
  }, {
    "reviews" : {
      "test2" : "review2"
    }
  } ]
}
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

The serialization works fine. But after deserialization, both review1 and review2 are LinkedHashMap. I want review1 and review2 to be their actual types which are Hashtable to review1 and HashMap to review2.  Is there any way to achieve this?

I don't want to use `mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);` because it will add the type info for all json properties in the json message. And if there is any better way to do it I don't want to use customized deserializer either. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question on Jackson user forum and they suggest to customized the `TypeResolverBuilder` and set it in the ObjectMapper instance.

`ObjectMapper.setDefaultTyping(...)`

My customized `TypeResolverBuilder` is below and it solved my problem.

```
public class MapTypeIdResolverBuilder extends StdTypeResolverBuilder {

    public MapTypeIdResolverBuilder() {
    }

    @Override
    public TypeDeserializer buildTypeDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config,
                                                  JavaType baseType, Collection<NamedType> subtypes) {
        return useForType(baseType) ? super.buildTypeDeserializer(config, baseType, subtypes) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeSerializer buildTypeSerializer(SerializationConfig config,
                                              JavaType baseType, Collection<namedtype> subtypes) {
        return useForType(baseType) ? super.buildTypeSerializer(config, baseType, subtypes) : null;
    }

    /**
     * Method called to check if the default type handler should be
     * used for given type.
     * Note: "natural types" (String, Boolean, Integer, Double) will never
     * use typing; that is both due to them being concrete and final,
     * and since actual serializers and deserializers will also ignore any
     * attempts to enforce typing.
     */
    public boolean useForType(JavaType t) {
        return t.isMapLikeType() || t.isJavaLangObject();
    }
}
```

This solution requires both server side and client side to use the customized `TypeResolverBuilder`. I know it is not ideal, but it is the best solution I found so far. The details of the solution can be found in this [post](http://geekspearls.blogspot.com.au/2015/10/jackson-serialization-of-map.html) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

The `readValue` call has no idea where the input JSON came from. It doesn't know that it was generated from a `Hashtable` or a `HashMap` or a `TreeMap` or any other type of `Map`. All it has to work with is the target type, `Shelf`, and its nested `Book`. The only thing Jackson can introspect from `Book` is that it has a field of type `Map`.

`Map` is an interface. Since you can't instantiate an interface, Jackson has to make a decision on the implementation type of `Map` that it wants to use. By default, it uses `LinkedHashMap`. You can change the default by following the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375069/how-to-change-jacksons-default-concrete-map-type).

An alternative is to declare the field with the concrete type you want

```
private HashMap<String, Object> reviews;
```

Now Jackson knows to deserialize the JSON into a `HashMap`. Obviously, this will only work with a single type.

The actual *solution* is for you not to care about the actual implementation class. You decided it was going to be a `Map`. You shouldn't care what implementation it uses under the covers. Use the power of polymorphism.

(Note that the use of `Hashtable` has long been discouraged.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm actually re-engineering legacy code to put it behind a RESTful API. One part of the code has a structure similar to the code I posted. It has its own implementation of Map which extends Hashtable. And it overrides get() method to always return the String representation of the value in the map. If I leave it to Jackson's default LinkedHashMap, the get() method will return Integer if the value is an Integer, that breaks the function of the code.